# Is there a v$sql for stored procedures in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Does Oracle provide some performance views like v$sql for stored procedures?
I would like to gather some statistics for stored procedures (time spend executing, cpu time, number of executions etc)

Answer (score -1):

v$sql captures procedure calls. You can check by running the following:

```
select * from v$sql
where lower(sql_text) like '%begin%'
and trim(lower(sql_text)) not like 'select%'
and trim(lower(sql_text)) not like 'insert%'
and trim(lower(sql_text)) not like 'update%'
and trim(lower(sql_text)) not like 'merge%'
and trim(lower(sql_text)) not like 'delete%';
```

ETA: further testing reveals that only some pl/sql gets stored in v$sql, and either my google-fu is weak or there's not much out there about what does and doesn't get stored.

Here's the test I did:

```
declare
  fred varchar2(10) := 'test';
begin
  select dummy
  into   fred
  from   dual;
end;
/

-- run the above pl/sql and then run the sql below:

select * from v$sql where lower(sql_text) like 'fred';
```

No rows were returned.

ETA2: as best as I can find, v$sql shows the contents of the shared SQL area, so I can only assume my anonymous block is not being stored there.

Comment: perfectly fine; if you look, I've only excluded rows that *start* with a dml operation (so as to exclude sql statements that have a column name containing "begin").